# Load sdcard video through html5-- android

Tags: android, html, video

I am new to html5, can anyone help me how to load html video tag which is to load videos from sdcard. I tried to implement

`<video width="320" height="240" controls  onclick="this.play();>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

but this html is not loaded videos from sdcard. can anyone guide me how to load videos from local sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

Its not allowed due to security reasons,the HTML5 Filesystem API allows web pages to open and manipulate files only within a sandboxed filesystem, and the limits of this  Sandbox are  sadly decided by the browser.

One workaround that is possible is that you can make an  file input element and allow user to choose a video file and then pass it as  the video element's `src` attribute

Please also note that without adding the `file:`  suffix the video will not play ,
so make sure that the syntax of the video tag is something like this

```
<video width="365" height="200" src="file:///sdcard/Download/video.mp4" controls autobuffer></video>
```

this trick is only known to be working with the default chrome browser.

So, no, there is no way to do precisely what you want, for security reasons, but there are some workarounds that you can try.

**Update 1:**

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>
$(document).on('ready',function(){
var video = $("#video");

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('video.*')) {
        continue;
      }



      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
        video.get(0).src = e.target.result;
        console.log(video.get(0));
        video.get(0).play();


          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = "a video file";
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

});
```

using the following code you can read a video file and pass it to the video element and play it.

PS: the only issue is that it first loads the video file in the memory and if video is too large it crashes the browser on. so kindly check if this trick works for you

Comment: Thank you so much or replies. is it possible to run the the above html in webview, can you please explain me. I spent time more than 3 days for this, but still dint get proper solution.

Comment: @HariRam: please check the updated answer and try if this hack can help you.<fingers crossed> :)